# How to get count of elements Json Response using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to get count of  Json elements from Json Response using JMeter
For example: from below response the count is 3. How to retrieve this value ?

[{
"key": "1",
"description": "Goods"
}, {
"key": "2",
"description": "services"
}, {
"key": "3",
"description": "tax"
}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON JMesPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) and [length() function](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#functions), configuration would look like:

[image]

and refer extracted array length as `${foo}` JMeter Variable where required.

Alternatively go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

```
vars.put('foo', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).size() as String)
```